# AngularJS: Using two-way data-binding to reload query

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I'm trying to solve an issue where a two-way data-binding exists between a query being called with a parameter and that parameter dynamically changing with an input checkbox, but the query itself is not changing.

From the view:

`<input type='checkbox' ng-model='checkbox' />`

From the controller:

```
$scope.checkbox = false
$scope.items = Item.query({someKey: $scope.checkbox});
```

When `checkbox` is **true**, a small number of items are listed.
When `checkbox` is **false**, a large number of items are listed.

The `checkbox` can be toggled true and false, but it seems that it doesn't have an effect on the query.
Has someone ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-run the query each time the checkbox changes.  Take a look at [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Something like:

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-model='checkbox' ng-change="requery()" />

$scope.requery = function(){ 
   $scope.items = Item.query({someKey: $scope.checkbox});
};
```

That may not be exactly right--usually you set your value ($scope.items) in the success method of an ajax call (I assume that's what Item.query does).